# Correlation among variables (categorical, binary and numerical)

Tags: python, classification, statistics, feature-selection, correlation

I have the following data

```
 Prefix Label   Year    Symbols Tags    %_Men   Prop    Uni_Role    Uni_Role_2  #_Cars  #_App
    0   IN  0.0     1996    []        []    0.08    0         11         22           0     1
    1   IT  0.0     2000    []        []    0.00    0         2          46           1     1
    2   ES  1.0     1999    []        []    0.10    0         10         30           0     1
    3   UK  1.0     1999    [!]      [!]    0.07    1         10         25           0     1
    4   USA 0.0     2007    []        []    0.07    0         11         23           0     1
    6   Republic of San Marino 0.0  1996    []  []  0.07  0   10         20           0     1
    7   USA 0.0     2002    []        []    0.05    0         5          22           0     1
    8   IN  0.0     2008    []        []    0.03    0         4          18           0     1
    9   IN  0.0.    1997    []        []    0.04    0         9          19           1     1
    10  IN  0.0     1997    []        []    0.06    0         8          20           3     1
```

I would like to study correlation among variables (target variable is `Label`). Since there is a mix of categorical (including lists, under Symbols and Tags columns), numerical and binary variables. For categorical variables probably I should consider Chi-Square, for numerical Pearson. I do not know how to get information from binary, but I know that it should not be possible to apply Pearson.
The problem is a classification one, where I should predict the status of a citizen.
Have you had similar problems? Any idea on how I could do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some distance/dissimilarity functions for two binary/boolean vectors such as Jaccard distance and  [Hamming distance](https://simeon.fandom.com/wiki/Hamming_similarity_for_vectors). You can check them from scipy's [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/spatial.distance.html). You can calculate similarities between two boolean columns by using these distance functions.

```py
from scipy.spatial import distance
distance.hamming([1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0])
0.66666666666666663

from scipy.spatial import distance
distance.jaccard([1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0])
1.0
```